# Include header and footer on Structure group level instead of page template level

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2

We have a running website with a standard header and footer, linked in using the include page on the page template:

[image: Screenshot of include elements]

We are now looking into translating part of the site into several different languages. Each of these languages will need their own header and footer. Now, if we can avoid it we don't want to duplicate all the page templates with new headers and footers, and adding them in as part of the content rather than using the include in the page template is also not a great solution. Would it be possible to define this header and footer of for example Structure group level using something like a metadata schema like we do in this picture for a submenu?

[image: Screenshot of structure group properties with metadata schema using a component]

Important is that we cannot change blueprints.

Comment: Christel , Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, Thanks for sharing the Tridion version please let us know if you are using DXA if so what is the version , refer to https://docs.sdl.com/784837/704733/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/configuring-the-web-application-for-multilingual-websites

Comment: How have you structured your websites... isn't /system/include/header specific to each language variant? You say you can't change the Blueprint - would be useful to get a glimpse of how it's setup for one language site?

Comment: refer to https://docs.sdl.com/784837/701374/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/managing-other-website-content  link

Comment: Can you clarify how you have set up different languages websites blueprint? since you mentioned you can't change the blueprint? does it mean you managing all different language websites in the single publication?

Comment: We currently do not have different language websites. We're just now looking into making (a part of) the website available in more than one language. We currently have the 100 level Master, the 200 level Content and a 400 level for the 2 domains we're running